# Repeated field not validating in symfony2

Tags: symfony

```
//-- this is my controller code------

$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->add('curpass', 'password')
                ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
                    'type' => 'password',
                    'first_name' => " new Password",
                    'second_name' => "Re-enter Password",
                    'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.'
                ))
                ->getForm();

//----this is my twig code-----

<form action="#" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Can you suggest me what is wrong in my code? It is not comparing both password field 'new Password' and 'Re-enter Password'.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/repeated.html):

> This is the actual field name to be used for the first field. This is
>   mostly meaningless, however, as the actual data entered into both of
>   the fields will be available under the key assigned to the repeated
>   field itself (e.g. password). However, if you don't specify a label,
>   this field name is used to "guess" the label for you.

This means you cannot set the label using the first_name and second_name but you have to use options and passing an array with the label. I didn't found any solution to change the label of the second field though.

**Try removing the first_name and second_name and see if it works.**